# Generated public rsa key on mac for use with git, but can't locate it?

Tags: git, macos, posix, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm on mac os X (new to it) and need to generate a public rsa key for use with git (think I got that right). I'm following the directions here:

http://help.beanstalkapp.com/faqs/git/generating-and-adding-ssh-keys-on-mac-os-x

and have generated the key named (id_rsa.pub) in my home directory, but I don't see it there when I do ls, or when I view through the file explorer gui. Is it like a hidden file or something? How can I see it? I need to email the public key to someone,

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default it stores the key in the `~/.ssh` directory, which is hidden.
All directories that start with a period are hidden, but can be seen either by directly naming them or by specifying the `.`, as in:

```
ls .*
```

So to get a copy, you can type `cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/` and it'll appear in your home directory.

Answer (score 7):

you can directly **copy** the key to the clipboard by executing this command in your terminal

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command can be used to copy the **public key** in your clipboard.

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mac book

To list generated ssh key

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

To get public key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_edxxxx.pub
```

Copy the public key and paste them into your GitHub or Gitlab account

To verify authenticity
For GitHub :

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

For Gitlab :

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

For custom gitlab account:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.yourcompany.com
```

To add them in known host list type: yes